# Which tools are used to write acceptance tests for Python web applications (django)?

Tags: python, django, acceptance-testing, user-acceptance-testing

I've found only two:

- http://splinter.cobrateam.info/
- http://lettuce.it/index.html

I'd like to know you practices and experiences with these (or other) tools.

Comment: This is the use-case for a community wiki, and not a "Q&A" (i.e. 'has a correct answer') Right?  Paging @danielrosman or someone with appropriate moderator privileges.

Comment: +1 community wiki. a nice list of python web testing tools on stack might be nice, should i start with my answer? :)

Answer (score 2):

In my experience, Robot Framework (http://robotframework.org/) is an amazing framework which can be combine with RIDE to write acceptance tests in a BDD way.
It supports many libraries (including selenium) and lets you extend it by creating your own, everything in a very simple way.
This is where I started from a couple of years ago: http://www.wallix.org/2011/07/26/how-to-use-robotframework-with-the-selenium-library/

Comment: The robot framework isn't an IDE, it's a framework for running tests. There is an IDE for robot (RIDE), but the framework and the IDE are two separate things. You can use robot framework without RIDE.

Comment: True. Thanks about the correction, will update my answer

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to take a look also to Selenium IDE:

http://seleniumhq.org/download/

It worked well for a small set of test I need to write years ago

Comment: that was going to be my answer :D but i would rather say webdriver/selenium: http://code.google.com/p/selenium/